# Check if the password is the same symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, passwords, change-password

I want to allow a user to change their password from their personal space. For this, he must connect, so know his password.
It must proceed as follows to change are password:

- Enter the old password
- Enter the new password and confirm it [(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxVJa.png)

Except that I have a problem that I do not understand at all. I can not pass the password comparison step.
I check if the old password entered is different from the one in the database then, i send an error if it is. Otherwise, I send the new password to the database.

What do you think ? is this the right method?

*My controller*

```
     /**
     * @Route("/account/settings", name="account_settings")
     * @IsGranted("ROLE_USER")
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @param ObjectManager $manager
     * @return Response
     */
    public function settings(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, ObjectManager $manager): Response
    {
        $updatePassword = new UpdatePassword();
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(UpdatePasswordType::class, $updatePassword);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            if (!password_verify($updatePassword->getOldPassword(), $user->getHash())) {
                $form->get('oldPassword')->addError(new FormError('L’ancien mot de passe ne correspond pas'));
            } else {
                $newPassword = $updatePassword->getNewPassword();
                $hash = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $newPassword);

                $user->setHash($hash);
                $manager->persist($user);
                $manager->flush();

                $this->addFlash(
                    'success',
                    'votre mot de passe a bien été mise à jour'
                );

                return $this->redirectToRoute('account_index');
            }
        }

        return $this->render('front/account/settings.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

*My entity*

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class UpdatePassword
{
    private $oldPassword;

    /**
     * @Assert\Length(min=8, minMessage="Le mot de passe doit être composé d'au moins 8 caractères")
     */
    private $newPassword;

    /**
     * @Assert\EqualTo(propertyPath="newPassword", message="La confirmation du mot de passe ne correspond pas")
     */
    private $confirmPassword;

    public function getOldPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->oldPassword;
    }

    public function setOldPassword(string $oldPassword): self
    {
        $this->oldPassword = $oldPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getNewPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->newPassword;
    }

    public function setNewPassword(string $newPassword): self
    {
        $this->newPassword = $newPassword;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getConfirmPassword(): ?string
    {
        return $this->confirmPassword;
    }

    public function setConfirmPassword(string $confirmPassword): self
    {
        $this->confirmPassword = $confirmPassword;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

*My security.yaml file*

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_PRO: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_PRO]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        in_database:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            remember_me:
                secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
                lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
                path:     /

            provider: in_database

            form_login:
                login_path: account_login
                check_path: account_login
                default_target_path: account_index

            logout:
                path: account_logout
                target: account_login

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: "Except that I have a problem that I do not understand at all". What's that?

Comment: Try using [`isPasswordValid`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/d67289ca82b3c295e13aed684ac96f7396b025a1/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Encoder/UserPasswordEncoderInterface.php#L39) instead of `password_verify` and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57648624) recent [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57694350#57694626).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, we must go from `PHP 7.2` to `7.3.` In `Symfny 4.3.2`, password encryption is done `automatically`. It chooses the most used and most secure encryption algorithm of the moment but for it to work properly you have to update the php!

If you use docker, you have to do like this.

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

And do not forget the mysqli extensions.

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd
```